# Unable to get ibm_db up and working on Maverick

Tags: python, macos, ibm-db2

I am trying to get ibm_db up and working on OSX Mavericks. 
I am following the directions found in the [DB2 for MAC OS X](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797) and was able finish them successfully.

However, there is nothing in there for setting the environment variables:
I know I need to add this line: `export IBM_DB_HOME=/Users/db2inst1/sqllib` to a file somewhere. What file is it? I have tried `sudo vi /etc/launchd.conf` and when I go to `easy_install ibm_db` I am getting the following error:

```
Environment variable IBM_DB_HOME is not set. Set it to your DB2/IBM_Data_Server_Driver installation directory and retry ibm_db module install.
No eggs found in /var/folders/_z/2nmsjtjj23jdqb6tn0l2v6g0lc16cd/T/easy_install-HjFtty/ibm_db-2.0.5/egg-dist-tmp-omhhih (setup script problem?)
```

I feel like I am really close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I needed to edit `~./bash_profile` and put my IBM_DB_HOME in there. This took care of the problem and I was able to successfully install the python `ibm_db` package.

Answer (score 0):

**How to make ibm_db work on MAC**

Make sure that you has IBM DB2 EXPRESS 2 installed on your machine:
       https://www.ibm.com/analytics/us/en/db2/trials/?S_CMP=ECDDWW01&S_TACT=ACDB201

To install the DB2 EXPRESS 2 extact the files into your computer and:

```
cd ~/Downloads/expc ; sudo ./db2_install
```

Make sure that you has your $HOSTNAME variable properly configured:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 $HOSTNAME" >>/etc/hosts
```

Create another user using mac gui 
(System Preferences -> Users & Groups). Use Standard (Non-Admin) privileges.

Create the instance with these commands:

```
cd /opt/IBM/db2/V10.1/instance ; sudo ./db2icrt -u <newuser> <newuser>
```

Export the following variables

```
$ sudo -s
$ export IBM_DB_LIB=/Users/<username>/sqllib/lib64
$ export IBM_DB_DIR=/Users/<username>/sqllib
$ export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

Intall ibm_db

```
pip3 install ibm_db
```